# Wolfram alpha not recognizing e as a number?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, wolfram-alpha

So I got into wolfram to see whether I solved correctly an exercise.

More specifically the first-order derivative of $y(x)=e^x (ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+q)$.

Im solving by undetermined coefficients the particular solution of $y'''+3y''-6y'+6y=2x^4e^x$

[This is what Wolfram returned](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivative%20e%5Ex%20*%20(ax%5E4%2Bbx%5E3%2Bcx%5E2%2Bdx%2Bq))

Why is the first term multiplying $e^x$ with a $log(e)$, I mean, why isnt ${\dfrac{d e^x}{dx}} = e^x?$

Comment: If you need $e^x$ type $Exp[x]$

Comment: Damn man that was fast. Thanks and sorry for the dumb question.

Comment: Wasn't dumb, now you know more about Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: Also Wolfram Alpha recognizes Euler's constant by capital E.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a case of Wolfram Alpha being too smart for its own good. The input you entered was:

> [derivative e^x * (ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+q)](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivative+e%5Ex+*+(ax%5E4%2Bbx%5E3%2Bcx%5E2%2Bdx%2Bq))

Note that the expression uses the constants $a,b,c,d\,$. Apparently, this trips WA into assuming that $e$ must itself be such an arbitrary constant. If you change the expression to use, say, $p$ instead of $d$ then WA will assume that $e$ *is* the base of the natural logarithms, instead:

> [derivative e^x * (ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+px+q)](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivative+e%5Ex+*+(ax%5E4%2Bbx%5E3%2Bcx%5E2%2Bpx%2Bq))

The workarounds have already been posted in comments: use $Exp(x)\,$, or use the capital $E^x\,$.